# how to get limits UNDER argmax with substack, inside cases

Tags: cases, substack

When I use `\substack` together with `\max`, I get the limits UNDER the operator, which is what I want.

However, when I use \substack with `\operatorname{argmax}`, the limits are subscripts, which is not what I want.

Also, when I use `\substack` with `\max` inside of

```
\begin{cases}
...
\end{cases}
```

the limits are subscripts.

Is there a way to make the limits be UNDER `\operatorname{argmax}` inside of a "cases" environment?

My code (with undesirable behavior):

```
\[
\text{where } \pd{P[r][c]}{A[i][j]} =
\begin{cases}
1 & i,j = \max_{\substack{1 \le i' \le 3 \\ 1 \le j' \le 3} } A[(r-1)\times 2+i'][(c- 
1)\times 2+j']\\[30pt]
0 & \text{ else }
\end{cases}
\]
```

Code that does put limits UNDER the operator:

```
\[
P[r][c] = \max_{ \substack{1 \le i \le 3 \\ 1 \le j \le 3} } A[(r-1)\times 
2+i][(c-1)\times 2+j]
\]
```

Comment: What if you use \operatorname{argmax} \limits ...?

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't know about the * that I needed, as you described in your answer below. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome ..

Comment: Load mathtools and use dcases, it runs the cells is display math style, normal cases use text style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, a slight modification.

```
\operatorname*{argmax} \limits_{\substack{1 \le i' \le 3 \\ 1 \le j' \le 3}}
```

I think this solves your problem.

***Note:*** `\operatorname{}` without the asterisk cannot accept the command `\limits`.

The command `\limits` should also fix your other problem.

> Also, when I use \substack with \max inside of \begin{cases} \end{cases}, the limits are subscripts.